# Xamarin display html5, css3, js, ajax

Tags: c#, xamarin

I need display html5 document in my xamarin application, i need support for html5, css3, javascript and ajax. Is there any solution to display it?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/

Answer (score 0):

The built in `UIWebView` in iOS is always quite limited in what it can do. Especially when you want a lot of fancy stuff like the technologies you mentioned. In iOS8 the `WKWebView` and the WebKit framework was introduced which is said to be a lot better but I have yet to work with it. I believe Xamarin Forms uses  `UIWebView` under the hood though.

Comment: One of the big "issues" with `WKWebView` is the fact that it has issues loading **local** content if it is not all embedded into a single request (file). It is way faster then `UIWebView` due the Nitro engine, etc... but `UIWebView` is still supported since `WKWebView` is not a direct/drop-in replacement. If you are pulling your web content remotely, then `WKWebView` is the way to go...